# What is a noetherian category?

Tags: category-theory

What is a noetherian category?

I'm a little bit familiar with category theory, but I've no idea what this could be.

Do you know what it is good for or examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/noetherian+category :

A category $C$ is noetherian if  the class of objects of its skeleton is a set and every object in $C$ is a noetherian object.

For example you can take the category of finite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: What is it good for?

Comment: I just gave an example of such a category.

Answer (score 1):

OK, well a good start would be to [google "noetherian category"](https://www.google.com/search?q=noetherian+category&oq=noetherian+category&aqs=chrome.0.69i64j5j0l2j69i62l2.2911j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and strike upon the [nLab entry](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/noetherian+category) (which is the very first hit) which explains that a Noetherian category is an essentially small category in which the objects are all Noetherian objects.

<s>The "essentially small" part is unfamiliar to me, and a bit of a surprise since I suspected that the class of Noetherian modules for any ring would be a Noetherian category. Since such a category seems to frequently not be essentially small, I guess one would have to make additional restrictions. For example, the category of submodules of a Noetherian module over a simple Artinian ring would work, since there are only finitely many isotypes of submodules of such a module.</s>

---

While I was editing I see that Boris has suggested what looks like a very nice example of finite dimensional vector spaces, which is a really helpful illustration of "essentially small".

---

Hrm, well reading more at the link, and some help from Zhen Lin in the comments, I've learned that it *is* true that the category of Noetherian modules over a ring with identity form a Noetherian category. (I hoped as much!)

Comment: The cardinality of a finitely-generated $R$-module can be bounded in terms of the cardinality of $R$ and $\aleph_0$, so there is only a set of isomorphism classes of finitely-generated $R$-modules.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks: actually I figured out my (stupid) mistake. When it said "is a set" I thought I had read "is a finite set". Of course I should have picked up on that earlier while reading the vector space example... Dunno what's going on in the noggin.

Comment: @ZhenLin So it sounds like it might be true that the category of Noetherian modules over *any* ring is a Noetherian category?

Comment: That's correct.